# Error thrown when executing a stored procedure that returns no results

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, dapper

I am currently using dapper on one of our projects and we execute stored procedures all the time. In the first few methods everything was working fine when the stored procedure we execute returns rows.

Right now I'm facing an issue when I try to fetch data from an stored procedure that returns info when found. This is a very common use case (eg. logging users on the application). When calling the `Query` method, and the sproc does not return any row, dapper throws an `ArgumentException` with the message:

*"When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id Parameter name: splitOn"*

The code I'm using is:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();

    return conn.Query<Customer>(
            sql: "prc_GetCustomer",
            param: new { Parameter = p },
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I'm aware that there is a `Execute` method that should be used when the procedure is expected to not return any rows but it's really not my situation. Also, dapper exception is misleading, since I'm not using multi-mapping.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: is the stored procedure returning a dataset with zero rows or is it just not returning a dataset at all?

Comment: I could repeat the problem its when the stored procedure returns nothing at all.  It works fine if it just returns an empty result set in the same structure as the <Customer> object.  Is there a reason you can't return an empty dataset instead of nothing?

Comment: Right now this procedure returns nothing, I do agree that is not s good solution but we have a lot of legacy stored procedures like this. I just wonder if dapper couldn't check if there are no fields and just return default(T)

Comment: Yeah on the surface I am not seeing how to do it.  Even if you just use the Query method instead of Query<T> it throws the same ArgumentException

Comment: Can you clarify: is it returning zero grids? Or is it returning any empty grid?

Comment: @MarcGravell it's returning zero grids

Comment: @rocco ok: you state that you know about Execute, buy that it isn't the tight thing. But Execute is for *exactly* when no grids are coming back. So: why di you think Execute is incorrect here?

Comment: @MarcGravell I guess that is Execute is right on this purpose of running a command without a return grid but my situation is very specific. I have a number of stored procedures that does some logic and then return grids or not. Dapper expects that a command that is supposed to return rows to return a full or empty grid and sometimes it's not the case. I was thinking on something like SqlDataReader does on checking the HasRows property.

Comment: In that case, I guess you're going to have to either fix those stored procedures or find an alternative to Dapper. There's no reason why I sproc would return no grid instead of an empty one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the query does not return any result grids, you should use Execute, not Query.

Comment: I think that these stored procedures are using the wrong logic when it checks for something before returning a grid (or an empty one). It's a semantic thing that is suported by a regular DbDataReader so it came to this point. IMHO Dapper should support this kind of situation but I will accept the answer.

Comment: So if I read this right

PROC-A -> sometimes returns 0 records;

I get this error when it returns 0 records;

So in order to fix this I have to do an additional call to do a count to make sure I don't call this proc when it is in a state that doesn't return records?

Comment: @snafu no, unrelated. Returning zero rows from a select is very different to not doing a select at all. If it doesn't do a select: Execute.